# SWT Java: How to prevent window from resizing?

Tags: java, resize, window, swt

I want to disable resizing of window. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non resizable window with JFace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191515/non-resizable-window-with-jface)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can specify the `Shell` style bits by using the two-arg constructor.  The default style bits are `SWT.SHELL_TRIM`:

```
public static final int SHELL_TRIM = CLOSE | TITLE | MIN | MAX | RESIZE;
```

You actually want to exclude the `RESIZE` bit.  If you're creating your own `Shell`:

```
final Shell shell = new Shell(parentShell, SWT.SHELL_TRIM & (~SWT.RESIZE));
```

If you're extending `Dialog`, you can influence the shell style bits by overridding `getShellStyle`:

```
@Override
protected int getShellStyle()
{
    return super.getShellStyle() & (~SWT.RESIZE);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can control the furniture when you declare the shell. I think this example does what you want;

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class FixedWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();

        //final Shell shell = new Shell(display); //defaults
        //final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX); //can be maximised
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN ); // fixed but can be minimised
        //final Shell shell = new Shell(display,  SWT.TITLE ); // fixed, uncloseable, unminimisable can only be removed by OS killing JVM.

        Rectangle boundRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        shell.setBounds(boundRect);
        Rectangle boundInternal = shell.getClientArea();

        shell.setText("Fixed size SWT Window.");

        shell.open();

        final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

        text.setEditable(true);
        text.setEnabled(true);
        text.setText("Oh help!");
        text.setBounds(boundInternal);


        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {

            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, actually I solved it in meantime by adding: "new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE)", and your answer does the same but have additionally MIN

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure about it, but I think you can just drop SWT.Resize event like this:

```
shell.addListener (SWT.Resize, new Listener () {
    public void handleEvent (Event e)
    {
       return;
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work in practice - the resize listener is fired after the window has been resized, not before, so setting `e.doit` to false has no effect.  On some platforms, you can try setting the size of the shell **back** to what it was, but this looks weird on some platforms (especially with wireframe resizing, or platforms that allow a fair amount of resizing before firing that event.)  On other platforms, you actually get an infinite loop of events when you resize a shell inside a resize listener (unless you set a flag that you're changing the size.)