# How can I disable the java GUI wizard pages from resizing

Tags: java, swt, wizard

I am currently working with WizardDialog. I needed to fix a size for the wizardDialog, however I just realized that setting the page size doesn't mean the user cannot resize it later on. Which is not a desirable feature. How do I disable resizing? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740387/swt-java-how-to-prevent-window-from-resizing

Comment: Thanks! Saw that earlier but did not think it applied to me. Turned out it worked with a copy paste in  the class I was using to create wizard pages (the class inherites WizardDialog so the override worked perfectly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating the `WizardDialog` yourself set the shell style using something like:

```java
setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | getDefaultOrientation());
```

which is leaving out the default `SWT.MAX` and `SWT.RESIZE` flags.