# Resize SWT Table

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a wizard with table and button components. When I click to the add button I choose from dialog window what items should be added to the table. I confirm items, and then this ones appears in the table with scrollbar. But if I resize the wizard, the table size is changed. How to fix it?

Table before resize:

[image]

Table after wizard resize

[image: Table afterresize]

```
Composite compositeArea = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
layout.numColumns = 3;
compositeArea.setLayout(layout);
Table table = new Table(compositeArea, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
new TableColumn(someList, SWT.NULL);
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
```

Comment: Does this help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740387/swt-java-how-to-prevent-window-from-resizing). Notice the answer about event handlers...

Comment: So you _don't_ want the table to resize with the dialog? You could set `GridData#widthHint` and `GridData#heightHint`, but I'd not recommend that unless necessary.

Answer (score 1):

** Please note that the use of [`HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html&anchor=HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL) and [`GRAB_HORIZONTAL`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html&anchor=GRAB_HORIZONTAL) is discouraged. Instead, you should be using the [`public GridData(int, int, boolean, boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html&anchor=GridData(int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean)) constructor. **

---

To slighly simplify your code snippet (only one column on the composite, and only one default table column - see full code below):

```
// ...
final Composite compositeArea = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
compositeArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
compositeArea.setLayout(new GridLayout());

final Table table = new Table(compositeArea, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
// ...
```

[image]

...and we see that the `Table` isn't fitting in the available space or showing the scrollbar as expected, and the same occurs when the `Shell` is resized.

In answer to your question, this is because the layout data of the `Table` doesn't know how to layout *vertically* - you've only specified two *horizontal* style attributes.

If we instead use the suggested constructor:

```
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

[image]

...the `Table` takes the available space correct, shows the scrollbar, and updates correctly when the `Shell` is resized. Using the layout data, we've told the `Table` to fill the available horizontal space, and the `Table` will display the scrollbar if necessary.

---

Full example:

```
public class TableResizeTest {

    private final Display display;
    private final Shell shell;

    public TableResizeTest() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setMaximized(true);

        final Composite parent = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        // -- snippet --
        final Composite compositeArea = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        compositeArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        compositeArea.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final Table table = new Table(compositeArea, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        // table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        // -------------

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE).setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.setSize(300, 300);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new TableResizeTest().run();
    }

}
```