# Minimum size of swt shell and components

Tags: java, swt

How can I set a minimum size of the shell in swt? For example I have added a search field in my shell but I can shrink the shell almost completely and then the search field isn't completely visible. Can I change a property of the search field to stop resizing if it would be unseen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any property or anything like that to prevent the resizing.

You can use `Shell.setMinimumSize` to set a minimum width.

**Update**
The following resize code from the original version of this answer doesn't work as resize is called after the window is resized

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, event -> {
  Shell eventShell = (Shell)event.widget;

  Point size = eventShell.getSize();

  if (size.x < 100 || size.y < 100)
   {
     // Stop the resize event
     event.doit = false;
   }
});
```

Comment: This won't work. Cancelling the event has no impact at all for this. I just tested this with swt v4.29 on Windows 11 and it sounds like it never worked like this as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740387/swt-java-how-to-prevent-window-from-resizing#comment9422674_7740773

Comment: @CodeShark Agreed, not sure if it ever worked or not. Added Shell.setMinimumSize which does the same thing and does work.